# Proof of the trigonometric identity $\frac{1 + \tan x}{1 + \cot x} = \frac{1 - \tan x}{\cot x - 1}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm stuck on the equation 
$$\frac{1 + \tan x}{1 + \cot x} = \frac{1 - \tan x}{\cot x - 1}$$
I've tried everything I could think of to solve it but nothing is working. Where do I start?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: ... However, as a 2 year member of this site, you should know that, and not rely on others to typeset your equations :)

Comment: Before the edit, wasn’t there a cotangent instead of cosine in the denominator on the RHS?

Comment: Yes. It was supposed to be cot

Comment: @Grimestock: Your first revision had cosine in the denominator on the left, not cotangent.

Comment: @MartinR That was my fault.  I am still waking up.

Comment: Ok, now they’re both showing cotangent, but originally one was cosine, right?

Comment: @Joe After checking the revision history, I found that you are correct.  You can check the revision history by clicking on the edited [n] minutes ago button.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, thanks, I did not realize that feature existed!

Answer (score 1):

The identity is not true. For $x \in (0,\frac {\pi} 4)$ LHS is positive and RHS is negative .

Answer for the revised version: cross multiply; it is fairly easy to verify that $(1+\tan x) (\cot x -1)=(1+\cot x) (1-\tan x)$. The only thing you need is the fact that $\tan x \cot x=1$.

Comment: I apologize.  I misread a cotangent as a cosine.  The error has now been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\boxed{t = \tan x}$ and noting that $\boxed{\cot x = \frac{1}{t}}$ you have

$$t = t\frac{1-t}{1-t} = \frac{1-t}{\frac{1}{t}-1} = \frac{1-\tan x}{\cot x - 1}$$

Similarly,
$$t = t\frac{1+t}{1+t} = \frac{1+t}{\frac{1}{t}+1} = \frac{1+\tan x}{1+\cot x}$$

Answer (score 0):

For non-zero finite $\tan x,$

$$\dfrac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}=\dfrac{1+\dfrac1{\cot x}}{1-\dfrac1{\cot x}}=?$$

Now rearrange